# What is the result of $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)}{n+\frac{1}{k}}$?

Tags: limits

What is the result of the following:

$$ \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty }  \frac{\sin( \frac{1}{n}) }{n+1}+ \frac{\sin( \frac{2}{n} )}{n+ \frac{1}{2} }+\cdots+ \frac{\sin( \frac{n}{n}) }{n+ \frac{1}{n} }=\text{?}$$

Answer (score 1):

For first,
$$ \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin\left(\frac{k}{n}\right) = \int_{0}^{1}\sin(x)\,dx = 1-\cos(1) = \color{red}{2\sin^2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$
by Riemann sums. However,
$$ 0\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\sin\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)\left(\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n+\frac{1}{k}}\right)\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k}{n}\cdot\frac{\frac{1}{k}}{n\left(n+\frac{1}{k}\right)}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n^3}=\frac{1}{n^2}$$
hence we have already computed our limit.